# Should mutex be used when inserting element in vectors?

Tags: c++, c++17

I know that need mutex when try to delete an element from a vector.

so, I wrote a sample code to check this.

```
class Test
{
public:
    Test(int idx) : m_index(idx) {}
    int     m_index = { -1 };
    int     m_count = { 0 };
};
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Test>>  m_vec;
std::mutex                          m_mutex;


void foo1() // print element data
{
    while (true)
    {
        std::unique_lock ulock(m_mutex);
        for (auto& e : m_vec)
        {
            e->m_count++;
            printf("%d : Count : %d\n", e->m_index, e->m_count);
        }
        ulock.unlock();
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(5));
    }
}

void foo2() // Only insert element
{ 
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dis(0, 99);

    while (true)
    {
        int t = dis(gen);
        if (t >= 0 && t < 10)
        {
            //std::unique_lock ulock(m_mutex);
            m_vec.push_back(std::make_unique<Test>(m_vec.size()));
        }
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(t));
    }
}

void foo3() // Only remove element
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dis(0, 99);

    while (true)
    {
        int t = dis(gen);
        if (t >= 0 && t < 10)
        {
            std::unique_lock ulock(m_mutex);
            if (m_vec.empty() == false)
                m_vec.erase(m_vec.begin());
        }
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(t));
    }
}

int main()
{
    m_vec.push_back(std::make_unique<Test>(1));
    m_vec.push_back(std::make_unique<Test>(2));
    m_vec.push_back(std::make_unique<Test>(3));
    
    std::thread t1(foo1);
    std::thread t2(foo2);
    std::thread t3(foo3);

    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    t3.join();

    return 0;
}
```

If I proceed with erase() without using mutex, segment fault almost immediately occurred.

So I used mutex for the erase() routine, which seemed to work normally.

About 10 minutes later, however, a nullptr exception occurred when referring to e in the foo1() function.

Q1. **push_back** inserts data at the end. But why does the NULL error occur at the middle point? ex. vector size: 521, error index: 129)

Q2. When using ordered containers such as vector and deque, do I need mutex in insert functions?

Q3. What about Unordered containers? (like, unorderd_map)
(Remove mutex from insert and operate without any problem for about 20 minutes.)

Comment: General note: If you have [good documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/) and it doesn't call an class or action out as thread safe, it almost certainly won't be.

Comment: Note on edit: Rather than manually unlocking the `unique_lock`, insert another code block. Eg `while (true) { { std::unique_lock ulock(m_mutex); /* critical section code */ } std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(5)); }`

Comment: Side note: Be really careful editing question after they've received quality answers that you don't render the answers obsolete or make them outright wrong.

Comment: @user4581301 I'm sorry. I'll put off revising the text for a while. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: @mystes Rather than editing the existing content, you should provide any changes as updates following the existing content. That way, comments/answers referring to the old content are not invalidated

Comment: Regarding *Remove mutex from insert and operate without any problem for about 20 minutes*, that's called getting lucky. Or unlucky, depending on how you look at it. I'd much rather have the program go BOOM! or show an obvious error in the output than have a ninja bug that slips through without notice until after people suffer grievous harm.

Comment: It was simply lucky to operate like this! I thought it was okay for the unordered type.

Comment: Q1: In `foo1` you're iterating over the vector. In `foo3` you erase the first element of the vector. Whenever you erase the first element you invalidate all the references that come after it. In `foo2` you push_back without a mutex lock. `std::vector` is NOT thread safe. Don't do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`foo2()` is accessing/modifying the `vector` outside of the `mutex` lock. As such, `foo1()` and/or `foo3()` (which do use the `mutex`) are able to modify the `vector` at the same time as `foo2()`. That is *undefined behavior*.

> When push_back inserts data at the end, why does the middle point (ex. vector size: 521, error index: 129) Null point error occur?

Pushing a new element into a `vector` may require it to reallocate its internal array, thus moving all of the existing elements to a new memory block.  You are doing that in `foo2()` without the protection of the `mutex` lock, so it is possible that the elements which `foo1()` and `foo3()` are accessing may disappear behind their backs unexpectedly.

Erasing elements from a `vector` will not reallocate the internal array, but it may still shift elements around within the array's existing memory.

> When using ordered containers such as vector and deque, do I need mutex in insert and delete functions?

Yes.  All standard containers are not thread-safe, so modifications must be serialized when used across thread boundaries.

> What about Unordered containers? (like, unorderd_map) (Remove mutex from insert and operate without any problem for about 20 minutes.)

Same thing.

Comment: I modified the code as you advised. Is mutex required in all cases when dealing with the same container variable in a multi-threading environment?

Comment: @mystes when making modifications to the container, yes. Whether you use a `mutex` or other suitable synchronization mechanism is up to you.